# How to add multiple key values at once

Tags: python, dictionary

As in the code below, I am trying to compute some things and put them into a dictionary. However, as the code below shows, I have to run `bct.charpath` multiple times to assign the outputs of the function to different key values, which means that unnecessary computation is required, as the same function will be run multiple times.

Is there a way to define the dictionary so that the `bct.charpath` is run only once? (for ex, by defining multiple keys of a dictionary at once??

```
def scalar_properties(self):
        data_dict = {
            "char_path_len" : bct.charpath(self.dist_mat)[0], 
            "global_efficiency" : bct.charpath(self.dist_mat)[1], 
            "graph_radius" : bct.charpath(self.dist_mat)[3], 
            "graph_diameter" : bct.charpath(self.dist_mat)[4],
        }
        return data_dict, data_dict.keys()
```

(I am aware that I could move the `bct.charpath` outside of the dictionary definition and doing sometinag like `a, b, c, d, e = bct.charpath(self.dist_mat)` then using those saved a,b,c,d,e, values when defining the dictionary would work. However, I was wondering if there was a cleaner way (with less lines of code) to do this!)

Thank you in advance for your answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `zip`

```
keys = ['char_path_len', 'global_efficiency', 'graph_radius', 'graph_diameter']
data_dict = dict(zip(keys, bct.charpath(self.dist_mat)))
```

Comment: What would you suggest I do if I also have to define other dictionary elements? For example, 


```def scalar_properties(self):
        data_dict = {
            "pos_strength_sum" : bct.strengths_und_sign(self.mat)[2],
            "char_path_len" : bct.charpath(self.dist_mat)[0], 
            "global_efficiency" : bct.charpath(self.dist_mat)[1], 
            "graph_radius" : bct.charpath(self.dist_mat)[3], 
            "graph_diameter" : bct.charpath(self.dist_mat)[4],```

Comment: The problem with this is that you were not assigning ALL of the elements,  You were assigning 0, 1, 3, 4.  This will assign 0, 1, 2, 3.

Comment: Oh yes I am aware of that, which is why I will modify the code accordingly! what I mean by defining other dictionary elements is, what should I do if, as in the comment above, there are other elements I want to add to the dictionary other than the results of `bct.charpath`

Comment: @DannyHan if you want something that is not straight forward you will have to do something explicit like the other answer.

Answer (score 2):

The answer seems obvious, so I'm wondering what I'm missing.

```
def scalar_properties(self):
        bcp =  bct.charpath(self.dist_mat)
        data_dict = {
            "char_path_len" : bcp[0], 
            "global_efficiency" : bcp[1], 
            "graph_radius" : bcp[3], 
            "graph_diameter" : bcp[4],
        }
        return data_dict, data_dict.keys()
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! I thought of that method too, but I was wondering if there was a shorter method of achieving it! (like a one-liner or something)

Comment: Why?  This works, is pleasantly parallel, and performs what is essentially an initialization function with adequate performance.  What's the point of spending more time on this?

Comment: Oh i see! Sorry I am not that experienced with python. Now that you say, I think your method will also be good! Thank you